# Problem with passing data from one component to another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a SearchForm component in the header where I fetch data from my API and get the data for my search and I need to use search in my software component to display the software I found.

SearchForm component:

```js
const SearchForm = ({ style }) => {

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  }

  useEffect(() => 

    if (shouldFetch) {

      (async () => {

        const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/?search=${search}`);

        const data = await response.json();

        setShouldFetch(false);

      })()

    }

  }, [shouldFetch]);

  const handleClick = () => setShouldFetch(true);

  return (
    <div
      className={styles["search-form"]}
      id={styles["search-form"]}
      style={style}
    >
      <form onKeyDown={OnKeyDown(handleClick)}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter something..."
          autoComplete="off"
          maxLength="30"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <SearchButton onClick={handleClick} />
        <small>ENTER</small>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export const SearchButton = ({ style, id, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      style={style}
      id={id}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />
    </button>
  );
};
```

And Softwares component:

```js
const Softwares = () => {

  const [softwares, setSoftwares] = useState([]);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(null);
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(null);
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = async ({ currentPage }) => {

    const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/?p=${currentPage}`);

    const data = await response.json();

    setSoftwares(data.results);
    setTotal(data.count);
    setTotalPages(data.total_pages);
    setValid(true);

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData({ currentPage: 1 });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    {
      valid &&
      <section className={styles.softwares}>
        ...
        {softwares.map(s => (
          <Article key={s.id} pathname={s.id} title={s.title} image={s.image} pubdate={s.pub_date} icon={s.category.parent.img} categoryID={s.category.id} categoryName={s.category.name} dCount={s.counter} content={s.content} />
        ))}
        <Paginator totalPages={totalPages} total={total} onMovePage={fetchData} />
      </section>
    }
    </>
  );
};
```

I can't use SearchForm in Softwares because in App.js they are "quite distant", I just wouldn't want to turn it all into one component.

Here's how it look like in App.js:

```js
const App = () => {

    ...

    return (

        ...

        <Header />

    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div id="content" className="left">
          <div className="inner">
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Softwares} />
              <Route path="/software/:id" exact component={SoftwareDetail} />
              <Route path="/category/:id" exact component={CategoryDetail} />
            </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        ...

    );
}
```

So what should I do?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do that. But in general, you should put the responsibility of fetching and storing the data in some different places. For example, you can use Context for this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext or react-dedux https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#:~:text=React%20Redux%20is%20the%20official,the%20store%20to%20update%20state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its a valid approach to move the shared state one component up, its called lifting state, here is the official reference https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html